# ImportError: No module named 'botocore.parameters'

Tags: python, aws-cli

After an upgrade on my awscli install, I ran in this error. I can't figure out the reason for that error. Can anyone help?

AWS Cli Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/aws", line 23, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/aws", line 19, in main
    return awscli.clidriver.main()
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/clidriver.py", line 44, in main
    driver = create_clidriver()
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/clidriver.py", line 53, in create_clidriver
    event_hooks=emitter)
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/plugin.py", line 44, in load_plugins
    modules = _import_plugins(plugin_mapping)
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/plugin.py", line 61, in _import_plugins
    module = __import__(path, fromlist=[module])
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/handlers.py", line 24, in <module>
    from awscli.customizations.ec2addcount import ec2_add_count
  File "/usr/share/awscli/awscli/customizations/ec2addcount.py", line 16, in <module>
    from botocore.parameters import StringParameter
ImportError: No module named 'botocore.parameters'
```

Any help will be apreciated!
Best regards

Comment: For some reason your `botocore` module doesn't match that which is required by awscli (botocore is the actual AWS-interfacing library for which awscli is just an interface).

Comment: I had this error on Ubuntu 14.04. The problem was that I had installed awscli with both apt-get and pip. Running `sudo apt-get remove awscli` and reinstalling with pip fixed it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The subpackage `botocore.parameters` was [split into serveral other modules](https://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#upgrading-to-0-64-0) with version `0.64.0` - but your version of `awscli` seems to rely on an older version as it expects this package to be present.

Depending on your way of installing `awscli` the problem might have different origins. When looking at the paths in the trace, it seems as if you've installed it with a package from your OS vendor. Instead of doing that you might drop those package and install it using `pip`.

`pip install awscli`

This will ensure the currently latest stable version of `awscli` to be installed. When you want to upgrade again in the future, run `pip -U install awscli`.

If you want to stick with the OS vendors version you probably want to reinstall awscli completely to fix this issue.

Comment: Thank you! After remove my SO installation of awscli and running an upgrade of the pip version it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Another easier solution would be to use the awscli install bundle provided by amazon.

You can find all the instructions here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-bundle.html